# Perform full-word substring replacement with pandas str.replace

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a sample data frame text column that contains strings including the word 'eng' and the word 'engine'.

```
ID  Text
1   eng is here
2   engine needs washing
3   eng is overheating
```

I want to replace the word 'eng' with the word 'engine'.  I use the code below:

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('eng', 'engine')
```

But this messes up my text in my second row.  The second row becomes

```
ID  Text
2   engineine needs washing
```

Is there a way to do the word replace so that it only replaces when the entire word says 'eng' only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a blank and fixed that problem from your own code

```
df['Text'].str.replace('eng ', 'engine ')
Out[736]: 
0            engine is here
1      engine needs washing
2    engine is overheating 
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Update

```
df.Text.str.split(' ',expand=True).replace('eng','engine').fillna('').apply(' '.join,1)
Out[752]: 
0           engine is here 
1     engine needs washing 
2    engine is overheating 
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hmm, this will still match '`blaheng `', when it should match just `'eng'`.

Comment: This must include word boundaries to match exact string.

Comment: and fail to match cases where the string ends with eng. its not a bad solution by any means if you know the edge cases, but it is not a very robust one.

Comment: @coldspeed yep you are right , and update ...I thought I should delete , but since many people already saw my fault I would like to correct it .

Comment: @pygo check the update

Comment: @ParitoshSingh check the update and thank you for point it out

Comment: @W-B, thnx , Happy New year !

Comment: @pygo you too :> happy new year

Answer (score 10):

Wrap your keyword with the word boundary character `\b`:

```
df['Text'].str.replace(r'\beng\b', 'engine')

0           engine is here
1     engine needs washing
2    engine is overheating
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

---

If you have multiple keywords to replace in this manner, pass a dictionary to `replace` with the `regex=True` switch:

```
repl = {'eng' : 'engine'}
repl = {rf'\b{k}\b': v for k, v in repl.items()}

df['Text'].replace(repl, regex=True)

0           engine is here
1     engine needs washing
2    engine is overheating
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice picture ! :-)

Comment: @W-B, which one :-)   coldspeed's pic ?

Comment: @W-B Thank you! New year, new profile :)

Comment: Good Pic with New Year Change! Bingo! Happy New Year.

Comment: @pygo tyvm, happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You could try regular expressions like so:

```
import re
df['Text'] = df['Text'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\beng\b', 'engine', x))
```

The \b Tags in this given regular expression match "wordboundaries" so 'eng' will be forced to be surrounded by spaces for example.